# Scoping States in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

In all applications there will always be this three scopes of state:
[image: States]

With Compose, a "Per Screen State" could be achieved by:

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
    ...
    composable(route) {
       ...
       val perScreenViewModel = viewModel()  // This will be different from
    }
    composable(route) {
       ...
       val perScreenViewModel = viewModel()  // this instance
    }
    ...
}
```

The "App State" could be achieved by:

```
val appStateViewModel = viewModel()
NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
    ...
}
```

But how about for "Scoped State"? How could we achieve it in Compose?

Comment: If you need a working solution for it; I currently use compose router [Github](https://github.com/zsoltk/compose-router) for it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is precisely what [navigation graph scoped view models](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel) are used for.

This involves two steps:

1. Finding the `NavBackStackEntry` associated with the graph you want to scope the ViewModel to
2. Pass that to `viewModel()`.

For part 1), you have two options. If you know the route of the navigation graph (which, in general, you should), you can use `getBackStackEntry` directly:

```
// Note that you must always use remember with getBackStackEntry
// as this ensures that the graph is always available, even while
// your destination is animated out after a popBackStack()
val navigationGraphEntry = remember {
  navController.getBackStackEntry("graph_route")
}
val navigationGraphScopedViewModel = viewModel(navigationGraphEntry)
```

However, if you want something more generic, you can retrieve the back stack entry by using the information in the destination itself - its `parent`:

```
fun NavBackStackEntry.rememberParentEntry(): NavBackStackEntry {
  // First, get the parent of the current destination
  // This always exists since every destination in your graph has a parent
  val parentId = navBackStackEntry.destination.parent!!.id

  // Now get the NavBackStackEntry associated with the parent
  // making sure to remember it
  return remember {
    navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)
  }
}
```

Which allows you to write something like:

```
val parentEntry = it.rememberParentEntry()
val navigationGraphScopedViewModel = viewModel(parentEntry)
```

While the `parent` destination will be equal to the root graph for a simple navigation graph, when you use [nested navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav), the parent is one of the intermediate layers of your graph:

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
    ...
  navigation(startDestination = nestedStartRoute, route = nestedRoute) {
    composable(route) {
      // This instance will be the same
      val parentViewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel(it.rememberParentEntry())
    }
    composable(route) {
      // As this instance
      val parentViewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel(it.rememberParentEntry())
    }
  }
  navigation(startDestination = nestedStartRoute, route = secondNestedRoute) {
    composable(route) {
        // But this instance is different
      val parentViewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel(it.rememberParentEntry())
    }
  }
  composable(route) {
     // This is also different (the parent is the root graph)
     // but the root graph has the same scope as the whole NavHost
     // so this isn't particularly helpful
     val parentViewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel(it.rememberParentEntry())
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that you are not limited to only the direct parent: every parent navigation graph can be used to provide larger scopes.

Comment: is there a way to know if a `composable` goes to the backstack vs `composable` getting disposed because of configuration changes (like device rotation) vs completely getting disposed as its no longer needed?

Comment: When it comes to specifically the behavior within a `NavHost`, the `onCleared()` of a scoped ViewModel will only be called when that destination (or set of destinations if you are using a navigation graph scoped ViewModel) is popped off the back stack and permanently destroyed.

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake, may I ask another question that is kind of related to this question. I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65075735/properly-scoping-viewmodel-across-screens

Comment: Any chance these implementations will make it to the official api?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Will `parentViewModel` be recomposed? The [hilt example](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation) for getting a viewModel scoped to a navigation route uses `remember`

Comment: @clmno - every call to `navController.getBackStackEntry()` should be remembered, yes. That ensures that you still get the same `NavBackStackEntry` while your destination is being animated out (i.e., after you hit the system back button).

Comment: Note that 
`remember {navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)}` can cause crashes and now triggers a lint warning ([more here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227382831)). 
  
 the solution is to use a the `backStackEntry` as a key to `remember` such as.    
    

`remember(navBackStackEntry) {navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)}`

Comment: @Guerneen4 where you getting the `navBackStackEntry` that is being used with remember?

Comment: @levi it's passed from withing the composable dsl, i.e., `NavHost(...){navigation(....){composable(...){navBackStackEntry -> ...}}}`

Answer (score 7):

From the [Compose and other libraries - Hilt](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt) doc

To retrieve the instance of a `ViewModel` scoped to navigation routes, pass the destination root as a parameter:

```kotlin
val loginBackStackEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent") }
val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel(loginBackStackEntry)
```

The same can be done without Hilt

```
val loginBackStackEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent") }
val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel(loginBackStackEntry)
```

This achieves the same thing acheived by @[ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961032/5698740) but lesser code

Note: The navigation graph has its own route = "Parent"

Full code example

**Scoped State Example with Jetpack compose and navigation**

```kotlin
// import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
// import androidx.navigation.compose.getBackStackEntry

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
        navigation(startDestination = innerStartRoute, route = "Parent") {
            // ...
            composable("exampleWithRoute") { backStackEntry ->
                val parentEntry = remember {navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent")}
                val parentViewModel = hiltViewModel<ParentViewModel>(parentEntry)
                ExampleWithRouteScreen(parentViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that 
`remember {navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)}` can cause crashes and now triggers a lint warning ([more here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227382831)). 
  
 the solution is to use a the `backStackEntry` as a key to `remember` such as.    
    

`remember(backStackEntry) {navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)}`