# Properly Scoping ViewModel Across Screens

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say we have a signup form which span multiple screens such as:
[image: Screen]

So I created a Scoped ViewModel spanning across these screens:
[image: Scoped Screens]

The problem is that since the state is scoped across screens, going:
`PersonalInfo Screen -> Set Username Screen -> (pressed back) Personal Info Screen` make it like this:
[image: State 1]

[image: State 2]

Notice that the `username` state is retained (since the ViewModel is scoped across the whole flow). So when the user goes back to `Set Username Screen` instead of a blank state, it retains the previous state. (But I need it to be cleared)

So what I really need is either:

1. Be able to know if the before screen gets disposed completely (not because of device configuration changes or it going to the backstack), so I could manually clear the state.
2. Or do something like this:

[image: End Scope]

which means have nested navigation over nested navigation (which I don't think is the right approach?).

3. Another choice is to have the ViewModel scoped only with the screen, and pass the state across screens during navigation, but I find that very tedious to do specially when there is alot of state to pass across multiple screens.

Am I missing something? Is there a suggested way to do this?

Comment: I know this may be an example here. But in the suggested "Enter and Review" flow it's usually really important to **retain** this information so the user doesn't have to reenter everything after spotting a mistake. This of course is another story when the choices depend on previous data in which case there are many solutions. I'd personally go with a single ViewModel where changing "base" data will clear "dependencies"