# same navigation drawer in multiple screen with viewmodel

Tags: navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

The navigation drawer must appear on each screen.
Whenever the user opens the drawer, if I'm logged in, the user's information should be entered, and if not, the ID and password should be entered as shown in the picture.

Even if the screen is moved, I want to have the user's information. Is there a way to use it in this case? I'm just wondering if I'm going to call the user's information from the view model of each screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scoping States in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955859/scoping-states-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Yeah, it' exactly what I want! Thanks