# Tie ViewModel with composable screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I don't know how correctly tie certain `viewModel` to certain compose screen.
For example, I have this

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = NavigationItem.Home.route) {
        composable(NavigationItem.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.History.route) {
            HistoryScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen()
        }
    }
```

and I have 3 viewModels: `HomeViewModel`, `HistoryViewModel` and `ProfileViewModel`.

How correctly create appropriate `viewModel` when a navigation goes into appropriate compose screen?

I want that every `viewModel` has a lifetime similar to a lifetime when I use a fragment's structure: while a `fragment` is live - `viewModel` also is live and when a `fragment` is stopped, `viewModel` is cleared.
In my app I will use dependency injection with `Hilt` but also I would like to know how to do it without any dependency

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory answer for your question?

Answer (score 1):

If your `ViewModel` can be perfectly scoped to one Composable, I think it is fine to inject your `ViewModel` into the Composable as a function parameter (as also seen in [this official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#5)). This allows good testability later, as you can simply pass a mocked `ViewModel` instance to your Composable. 
The default scoping differs between `androidx` and `Hilt` implementations:

**without Hilt:**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

@Composable
fun MyComposable (
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    // ...
}
```

The `ViewModel` by default is [scoped to the Activity or Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#top-level-functions-summary) that is containing the Composable, so it will stay in memory until the containing `Activity` is destroyed or the containing `Fragment` is detached.

**with Hilt:**

```
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel

@Composable 
fun MyComposable (
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    // ...
}
```

The `ViewModel` by default is scoped to the `NavGraphEntry`, meaning that the `ViewModel` will be removed as soon as the destination containing the Composable with the `ViewModel` is removed from the backstack.

---

For both approaches, you can modify the scope to any entry of a (nested) NavGraph, as described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69645158/8331157).

Note that it's a good practice to only inject a `ViewModel` into a top-level Composable. All nested Composables should directly receive the actual data or callback functions out of the `ViewModel` that they need instead of passing the ViewModel down the Composable hierarchy.